# INDEX(MATCH) function with open ended dates range condition to match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help to INDEX-MATCH a set of data with ARR_ON-DEP_OFF dates/times range columns to a set of data with WORK_START-WORK_STOP dates/times range, and to return the value from its match data set.

However, the lookup_value Dates/times range is within the lookup_array dates/times range. meaning, in chronological order, it would be ARR_ON-->WORK_START-->WORK_STOP-->DEP_OFF. So the formula I used below would require me to search outside the lookup_value boundary instead of within. Here, the lookup_value is WORK_START/STOP, lookup_array being ARR_ON/DEP_OFF. How can I overcome this open ended condition?

```
=INDEX($I$3:$I$1817;MATCH(1;(($F$3:$F$1817=A3)*($G$3:$G$1817<=B3)*($H$3:$H$1817>=C3));0))
```

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yipJU.png)

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share some sample data with us along with expected output, will help us to fix the issue!

Comment: If U are concern about #N/A getting in Col D,, the reason is non of the rows getting TRUE,, since all Match conditions are working as AND,, to check this you write this in `J29`,, =`F29=A29`, in `K29`,, `=G29<=B29` and next `=H29>=C29`,, yoi get `FALSE` ,, hope you got the issue!! Just to test the Formula replace `G34` & `H34` with `43698.3884` & `43698.8333` you get  `1` .

Comment: And your formula should an Array (CSE) formula, finish wit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.